# How to disable block selection in IntelliJ macOS

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, ide, selection, magic-mouse

I am working with Intellj IDE, but I found one thing really annoying. 
I am using macOS and Magic Mouse, when I try to select part of the code it often instead of selecting code tries to move block of code like that

[image]

This thing is really annoying and happens very often, so I wonder how to disable this "useful" feature ? And left only simple selection without block movement. 
Thanks

Comment: Disable `Settings > General > Editor > Enable Drag'n'Drop functionality in the editor`?

Comment: @BasLeijdekkers yeah !! it works, please post your comment as an answer, I will accept it

Comment: Thanks, I have added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Disable the following checkbox: `Settings > General > Editor > Enable Drag'n'Drop functionality in the editor`